# Query to split the column data into multiple columns with same special char

Tags: sql-server

I have column in table which has data in the form of A_B_C_D_E_F. I want this data in different columns of same row ie something like

[image]

I have created an sample code , which splits initial one ie A . But later it splits remaining like B_C_D_E_ etc..

---

```
declare @ni nvarchar (max)
declare @tt nvarchar (max)
declare @value nvarchar (max) 

set @ni = 'A_B_C_D_E'

set @turbine =(select LEFT(@ni , CHARINDEX('_', @ni) - 1)  )
set @value = (SELECT SUBSTRING( @ni, CHARINDEX('_', @ni) + 1, LEN(@ni) - CHARINDEX('_', @ni) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@ni) )
)  
)

select  @ni
select @tt
select @value
```

---

result is

A_B_C_D_E_F

A

B_C_D_E

Also here i have directly passed the data into a variable, however originally it is an column in an table and i have to pass it one by one. Please help in in resolving it.

Comment: [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) Or, if you are using 2016 version, `STRING_SPLIT()` built in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Col VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @t( Col )
VALUES  ( 'A_B_C_D_E_F');
```

**Query**

```
WITH SplitValues (Col , XmlCol)
AS
(
    SELECT Col
          ,CONVERT(XML,'<Value><value>'  
                   + REPLACE(Col,'_', '</value><value>') + '</value></Value>') AS xmlname
      FROM @t
)

 SELECT Col
      , XmlCol.value('/Value[1]/value[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col1
      , XmlCol.value('/Value[1]/value[2]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col2
      , XmlCol.value('/Value[1]/value[3]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col3
      , XmlCol.value('/Value[1]/value[4]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col4
      , XmlCol.value('/Value[1]/value[5]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col5
 FROM   SplitValues;
```

**Result Set**

```
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+
|     Col     | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+
| A_B_C_D_E_F | A    | B    | C    | D    | E    |
+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks M.Ali, But if you dont mind , please guide what was wrong in my method ,Also will it be possible to solve in that way as well?